# Stop array from printing 0 at end

Tags: arrays, c

I made a guessing game where a random number is generated and the user has 10 tries to guess it. At the end of the game, the program prints the array of all tries. When the user guesses correctly in less than 10 tries, the array prints out all tries and prints zeros after so that there are 10 elements in total because of the for loop.

If the number is 62 and it's guessed in 6 tries for example it looks like

`Your Tries: 50 90 60 65 63 62 0 0 0 0`

I want to make it so that the extra zeros are not printed at the end of the game.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  int s, n, v, win = 0, lose = 0;
  char c;

  srand( time(NULL) );
  s = rand () % 100 + 1;

  int tries = 0;
  int a[n];

  for (tries = 0; tries < 10; tries++)
    {
      scanf ("%d", &a[tries]);

      if (a[tries] == s)
    {
      win++;
      printf ("\nYou win!\n");
      printf ("Your Tries: ");
      for (tries = 0; tries < 10; tries++)
        {
          printf ("%d ", a[tries]);
        }
      printf ("\nTry Again? ");
      scanf (" %c", &c);
      if (c == 'n' || c == 'N')
        {
            printf("Your stats: %d Win, %d Lose", win, lose);
          return 0;
        }
      if (c == 'y' || c == 'Y');
      {
        tries = 0;
        s = rand () % 100 + 1;
        scanf ("%d", &a[tries]);
      }
    }

      printf ("The number is %s %d.\n", a[tries] > s ? "less than" : "greater than",
          a[tries]);
    }
    
  printf ("You input wrong number. You lose. The number is %d.\n", s);
  lose++;
  printf ("Your Tries: ");
    for (tries = 0; tries < 10; tries++)
        printf ("%d ", a[tries]);

        printf ("\nTry Again? ");
        scanf (" %c", &c);
  if (c == 'n'|| c == 'N')
    {
         printf("Your stats: %d Win, %d Lose", win, lose);
        return 0;
    }
  if (c == 'y' || c == 'Y');
  {
        tries = 0;
        s = rand () % 100 + 1;
        scanf ("%d", &a[tries]);
  }
}
```

Comment: `for (tries = 0; tries < 10; tries++)` : here you print all 10 values of the array regardless of the actual number of tries needed.

Comment: @anoer This declaration int a[n]; invokes undefined behavior because the variable n is not initialized and has an indeterminate value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you print out the last ten numbers using this:

```
for (tries = 0; tries < 10; tries++) {
   printf ("%d ", a[tries]);
}
```

however it continues to loop even if you have less than ten numbers, a short fix could be to add a variable to store the number of tries, increase it every try and then use it in the for loop to not print too much numbers:

```
int tries = 0;
int nb_tries = 0;
int a[n];

for (tries = 0, nb_tries = 0; tries < 10; tries++, nb_tries++) {
   scanf("%d", &a[tries]);
   if (a[tries] == s) {
      win++;
      printf ("\nYou win!\n");
      printf ("Your Tries: ");
      for (tries = 0; tries < nb_tries; tries++) {
         printf("%d", a[tries]);
      }
   }
}
```